# How do I download npm dependecies as part of Docker build

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile, npm-install, artifactory

We are using artifactory for retrieving npm packages and we need to use an `_auth` token in .npmrc (npm config) to fetch those npm dependencies required by my project.

I have read articles saying that `npm install` should be the first step in the Dockerfile so that it can be cached and we don't need to download dependencies every time we spin up a new docker image with a little change.

Also, it is a bad practice to put any `_auth` tokens in Dockerfile as part of the build.

So what is the best practice to do `npm install` in Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted because the question is not bad, maybe not great wording.
Essentially I believe the answer is that you need to copy the .npmrc from your environment into the docker image, like:

COPY .npmrc /usr/src/app/.npmrc

This is however scary because those are your credentials.
The NPM docs recommend that you pass in your auth token to the npmrc file as an env variable. That could also work in this case:
https://docs.npmjs.com/docker-and-private-modules

I believe that should be fine and keep your creds safe.

Comment: So if someone else has access to the image, will they be able to extract the environment variable from the image?

Comment: Mmm I think you should test that, but the idea is that the environment variables don't get saved. So if you pass the variable at build time then it's not hardcoded into the dockerfile

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to keep your credentials in your container, you can always remove it after the 'npm install' step is complete:

```
RUN npm install
RUN rm /usr/src/app/.npmrc
```

And then you can proceed with the rest of the build

Comment: For a real project, where do you store the .npmrc file? Definitely not in the repository along with the codebase right.

Comment: You can look at the `docker history` of the built image to find an image ID just before the `RUN rm` step, and `docker run` a container off that image to extract the credential.  If you `docker save` the image to a tar file the credential will be there as well.